# Drupal as backend for RESTful API?

Tags: drupal, rest

Are there any good write-ups on creating RESTful APIs with Drupal? I see the services API, which I guess is how it's done. What I'm looking for, I suppose is a comparison of drupal vs. other frameworks for that particular purpose.

Update - a bit more info:

In particular, I'm probably going to want to be returning json, and ideally using http request verbs (PUT, POST, GET, DELETE) properly with the common resource urls. I.e. http://mysite/api/widgets/1 (POST -> create, GET -> view, PUT -> update, DELETE -> delete) as opposed to http://mysite/api/widgets/1/delete

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I cannot compare with other frameworks, but [Service 3.x](http://drupal.org/node/736522) (that's version 3 of the [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module) provides a resource driven model for service with a REST backend (and an XML-RPC one). According to its documentation, you can [create a new resource type](http://drupal.org/node/783460) quite easily (if you are familiar with Drupal) using a simple API as it takes care of JSON[P]/XML parsing and serialization.

**Updated, prompted by David Eads' answer:**
I wouldn't start with Drupal and Services 3.x if the only end need is to build a RESTful service. They are not generic solution to build a data backend with a RESTful API. They should be used when what is needed is a CMS powered website exposing (parts of) its data through a RESTful API.

Answer (score 3):

Drupal Services 3.0 makes creating REST services much easier than it was with the previous versions (2.x). Also Services 3.0 works with Drupal 6 and Drupal 7.

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down. If I were building *just* a REST service from scratch I would not use Drupal. But if I happened to be building a Drupal site and needed a REST API - this is how I would go about it.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with Drupal 7 for such purposes, but over the summer I was tasked with building a RESTful service in Drupal 6.  Drupal 6 is fairly ill-suited to developing web services: the data model is built around content nodes, and the theming system is built around returning rendered HTML, so you wind up fighting with the framework a fair amount.

The Services module is decent, but ultimately, we went with [Django Piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/). Developing the service in Piston took far less time and was reliable and performant.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a good framework to built a RESTful architecture, I would greatly suggest:

[1. Recess Framework](http://www.recessframework.org/)
Well, recess is great, you direct routes to functions through URL and redirect control to other functions. It has a simple ORM that allows you to do great things in little time.

[2. Fat-Free Framework](http://fatfree.sourceforge.net/)
I've not used F3 but i know its simple, well-documented, allows  routing for restful architecture and has its ORM