# REST server in Drupal 6

Tags: rest, drupal, drupal-6

I would like to build a REST service in my Drupal module to expose the contents of my DB tables (not nodes, users, or other Drupal stuff). I've installed Rest_server and services modules but I've not found examples on creating REST services.
Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

The book "[Drupal web services](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/drupal-web-services)" by Packt is a good resource. They have free [Services introduction](https://hub.packtpub.com/introduction-drupal-web-services/) online too.

[image: Cover of Drupal Web services book]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: [Drupal as backend for RESTful API?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4604153/715002)

Also, did you had a look at the [Services drupal group](http://groups.drupal.org/services?page=1)?